# Can't set urxvt font in Fedora 24 with xfce

Tags: fedora, xfce, fonts, rxvt

I'm trying to set my terminal (urxvt) font to `9x15`. I add the following line in `.Xresources`

```
URxvt.font: 9x15
```

I save the file, I run `xrdb -load .Xresources`, but urxvt doesn't even open. If I remove that line and run `xrdb -load .Xresource` again it works, but only with the default font.

I already downloaded the `9x15` font (.pcf) and I ran `fc-cache -fv`, but still no change.

How can I change the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the corresponding font ***installed***.  With Fedora24, that is `xorg-x11-fonts-misc`, which you can install by

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-fonts-misc
```

As a side effect of installing the package, the RPM runs [`mkfontdir`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/mkfontdir.1.html), to establish the alias `9x15` (along with entering the XLFD name for the font).  Without both of those entries, you cannot use `9x15`.

Further reading:

- [RPMs for xorg-x11-fonts-misc](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xorg-x11-fonts-misc)
- [xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-16.fc24 RPM for noarch](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/24/i386/x/xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-16.fc24.noarch.html)